# ¿Cómo pasar una serie de datos por ajax a php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen día. Les explico: quiero pasar una serie de datos por AJAX a PHP desde una lista de elementos que se van agregando.

```
    var hora;
    var izq;
    var clase;
    var idEntrada;
    var datos;
    $('#publicar').on('click',function() {
        hora = $('#horaDesp').val();
        izq = $('#despIzq').children('section');
        izq.each(function() {
            clase = $(this).attr('class');
            idEntrada = $(this).children('div').attr('id');
            clase = clase.substr(8,2)
            datos = {
                'hora': hora,
                'id': idEntrada,
                'clase': clase
            }
        console.log(datos);
        });
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/funciones/programar.php',
            data: datos
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

Este es el JQuery para esa función, los elementos se crean dinámicamente desde otra función JQuery al `<div id="despIzq">` perfectamente. Y los datos del mismo se recorren cada uno desde el `.each()` hasta la consola mostrando los datos que necesito.

Mi problema es que cuando envío los datos mediante un objeto desde AJAX a PHP solo se envían los valores del último elemento. Por ejemplo:

```
    {hora: "01:01", id: "18", clase: "_b"}
    {hora: "01:01", id: "3", clase: "_n"}
    _n
```

Este sería el resultado obtenido del `console.log(datos)` y el último dato `_n` se obtiene mediante PHP

```
    <?php
    $clase = $_POST['clase'];
    echo $clase;
    ?>
```

No sé mucho sobre AJAX, imagino que debo pasar los datos en otro formato para que se lean todos los elementos con sus respectivos valores y no los valores del último elemento.

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada loop que hace el each remplaza al anterior valor de data, por lo tanto debes cambiar su tipo de dato y trabajarlo asi

```
var datos = [];

.each(function () {
datos.push({
'hora' : hora,
...
});
```

A la hora de enviar datos por ajax, envia un objeto de la siguiente forma

```
datos = {
    datos: datos,
};
$.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/funciones/programar.php',
            data: datos
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

PHP obtendrá un array o bien, un json que deberas parsearlo con json_decode

```
$datos = json_decode($_POST['datos']);

//Si se enviar directamente el array, obten el valor directamente asi
$datos = $_POST['datos'];

//La variable $datos ahora es un array, para recorrerlo hay diferentes métodos como for o foreach, te recomiendo este último
foreach($datos as $dato) {
  //fn para $dato
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo apliqué de esa manera y me devuelve en la consola un array con los valores de cada elemento, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero no se envían los datos por ajax a php, me aparece el `Undefined index` para cualquier variable enviada por `$_POST`. Sospecho que es porque se crea un array en la consola con el primer elemento, luego otro array con el primero y el segundo, y así hasta el último elemento.

Comment: intenta `print_r($_POST);` para ver los datos que estas recibiendo en php.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para que puedas ver los tipos de datos que están enviándose

Comment: @JonathanOrta estas enviando un POST y estas leyendo un GET

Comment: @JonathanOrta Ahora sí me funcionó, gracias por tu tiempo!