# ¿Cómo solucionar problema con función push() en JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una lista de opciones que se van creando dinámicamente en `$('#despIzq')` según se vayan seleccionando. Éste es el código JQuery que las genera:

```
$('.entradaDesp #blg h3').click(function(){
    var datos = $(this)[0].innerHTML;
    id_entr = $(this).parents('section').attr('data-id');
    $('#despIzq').append("<section class='entrDesp_b relativo' href='#"+id_entr+"'><h3>"+ "&nbsp" + id_entr + "&nbsp" + datos +"</h3><div class='entrDespBtn' id='"+id_entr+"'><h5>x<h5></div></section>");
)};
```

Luego envío los datos a PHP mediante Ajax así:

```
var hora;
var izq;
var clase;
var idEntrada;
var datos = new Array();
var fecha;
var dat;
$('#publicar').on('click',function() {
    hora = $('#horaDesp').val();
    izq = $('#despIzq').children('section');
    izq.each(function() {
        clase = $(this).attr('class');
        clase = clase.substr(8,2);
        idEntrada = $(this).children('div').attr('id');
        fecha = {
            'dia': dia,
            'mes': mes,
            'anio': anio
        }
        dat = {
            'id': idEntrada,
            'clase': clase,
            'hora': hora
        }
        datos.push({
            dat,fecha
    });
});
    datos = {
        datos
    }
    console.log(datos);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/funciones/programar.php',
        data: datos
}).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(datos)
    });
});
```

El código se ejecuta correctamente, pero solo una vez. Es decir, si se crean dos `<section class='entrDesp_b` y por error pulso el botón `$('#publicar')` sin colocar la hora, cuando la coloque y vuelva a pulsar el botón por segunda vez, aparece este error en consola:

```
Uncaught TypeError: datos.push is not a function at HTMLElement. 
<anonymous> (calendar.js:282)
at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (calendar.js:268)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Dejo el código HTML donde se crean los `<section class='entrDesp_b` para más detalles:

```
<div class="despIzq" id="despIzq">
  <h5 style="margin-botton:5px;">Programar para el día <span id="dia"></span> de <span id="mes"></span> de <span id="anio"></span></h5>
</div>
```

Nota: lo que quiero lograr es que se lean todos los `<section class='entrDesp_b` que se crean en `$('#despIzq')` y poder pasarlos por Ajax a PHP correctamente. 
Esta pregunta guarda relacion con esta otra: [¿Cómo pasar una serie de datos por ajax a php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302443/c%c3%b3mo-pasar-una-serie-de-datos-por-ajax-a-php) 
En ella me ayudaron a definir este fragmento de código:

```
var datos = new Array();

datos.push({
        dat,fecha
});
datos = {
    datos
}
console.log(datos);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'includes/funciones/programar.php',
    data: datos
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(datos)
});
```

Los objetos `fecha` y `dat` los guardé de esa manera por cuenta propia, ¿hay alguna manera mejor y más simple de hacerlo?
El objetivo es recorrer todos los `<section class='entrDesp_b` (me plantearon una solución usando la función `push()`) y se  pasar los datos `hora, clase, idEntrada` y `fecha` por Ajax a php.

Comment: No entiendo del todo tus explicaciones. Pero en el código defines a `datos` como un array, pero luego lo defines como `datos = { datos }` y puede que por eso el `push` falle en el segundo intento, porque ahí `datos` ya no es un array. De todos modos me parece que tienes una lógica algo liada, confusa y que quizá se pueda resolver el problema de un modo más sencillo, si logras exponer mejor (con más claridad) lo que se quiere lograr.

Comment: @Cedano He editado la pregunta para mejor comprensión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré que el error desapareciera limpiando el array `datos` de esta manera:

```
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(datos);
    datos = [];
});
```

No sé si sea la mejor forma, pero por el momento me funciona.